# Power from single XL-Motor to both rear and front axles

Tags: technic, building, motor, power-functions, wheel

I have a single XL motor and I would like to make my small car a 4WD one.

Currently, it is just front-wheel drive.

Any good instructions on transmitting power to rear wheels as well?

Comment: How that can be done depends heavily on the design of the car, so no general instructions exists. I simple cases, and very generally it's something like: add a gear to an axle driven by the motor, add another axle with a gear that connects to the first, and goes from that point to the back axle and transfer power to that. If there's a differential on the back axle, that's probably where you want to deliver power.

Comment: While @Henriksupportsthecommunity provided some generic details I find this question rather broad. Please edit it to ask some specific question you are facing with your 4WD implementation. One advise - XL has high torque, so brace everything as much as possible not to damage your gears and axles.